# Разные названия цыган

Tags: этимология, этноним

Сами себя цыгане называют ромалы. А откуда же взялось название "цыгане"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сербохорватское – циганин.
Греческое – цыган.
В русском языке это слово широко распространилось в конце XIII в.
В Древней Греции словом **«цыган»** обозначали кочевой народ, предками которого были древние индийцы. В русский язык это слово попало из сербохорватского в то время, когда цыгане стали активно селиться на территории Руси.
Родственными являются:
украинское – циган;
белорусское – цыган;
болгарское – циганин.

Comment: Откуда к греческом Ц???

Comment: К сожалению,  греческим не владею. Я думаю, вопросы не ко мне, а к авторам этимологических словарей. Н-р, к М. Фасмеру (на которого, кстати, Вы очень часто ссылаетесь): Заимств. через ср.-греч. τσίγγανος, стар. ἀτσίγγανος "цыган", которое возводится к ср.-греч. ἀθίγγανοι "hаеrеtiсi in Phrygia еt Lусаоniа рrаесiрuе degentes". Может, и нет "Ц" в греческом, но, наверное, при переводе какой-то согласный ассимилируется в звук\букву Ц.

Comment: Ну так я о том и толкую.  
τσίγγανος - Тсигганос, и не древнегреческое, с срелнегреческое.
А др.-греческое - ἀθίγγανοι - афиггане (мн. к ἀθίγγανος), слово, которое я и приводил.    
К Фасмеру вопросов здесь нет, а него русским написан перевод, а не транскрипция.    
  
Я тоже греческим не владею, но прочитать-то по буквам должен всякий, все-таки греческий алфавит в математике используется...

Comment: Мы или друг друга не понимаем, или толчём воду в ступе.

Comment: Не надо друг друга понимать. Просто примите к сведенью, что в греческом Ц не было и быть не могло. И не обратное обосновывать цитатами из Фасмера, у него все корректно.

Comment: См. Семенов А.В. 
ЭТИМОЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК
от А до Я
Издательство «ЮНВЕС»
Москва, 2003 г.

Все претензии к автору словаря. За букву "Ц" в греческом - спасибо.

Comment: @Соан, речь о звуке, а не о букве.